# populating existing SVG elements with JSON data using D3

Tags: json, parsing, svg, d3.js

What I want to achieve is an SVG that has several separate polygons that can be coloured according to a set of JSON data. I'm nearly there, but having problems with matching up the data objects with the SVG elements in the correct order.

I've created an SVG, which has several polygons such as

```
<polygon id="Zone2" fill="#DFECC5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="828.815,660.425 841.261,594.05    842.82,594.422 849.014,564.644 837.769,562.306 841.108,546.883 851.945,549.118 866.75,474.55 837.799,468.253 837.254,470.748    833.572,470.097 833.982,467.844 817.591,463.942 818.746,458.473 875.479,470.067 838.604,655.601 837.24,662.395  " style="fill: rgb(244, 246, 252);"><title>Car Park South, 1230</title></polygon>
```

Here's the JSON file I'm parsing:

```
{
"zoneData":[
    {"zoneID":"Zone1","name":"Car Park South", "value":1230},
    {"zoneID":"Zone2","name":"Outdoor North", "value":3453},
    {"zoneID":"Zone3","name":"Outdoor West", "value":2342},
    {"zoneID":"Zone4","name":"Outdoor South", "value":3453},
    {"zoneID":"Zone5","name":"High St. East", "value":1023},
    {"zoneID":"Zone6","name":"High St. West", "value":2322},
    {"zoneID":"Zone7","name":"Car Park North", "value":4562},
    {"zoneID":"Zone8","name":"Indoor North", "value":5644},
    {"zoneID":"Zone9","name":"Indoor South", "value":2356}
]
}
```

I've managed to parse everything and create a proper colour scale, and even use that scale to set colours for each polygon, but they are in the wrong order. The script is here:

```
d3.json("zoneAnalysisData.json", function(error, data) {

        var minDataValue = d3.min(data.zoneData, function(d) { return d.value; })
        var maxDataValue = d3.max(data.zoneData, function(d) { return d.value; })

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([minDataValue, maxDataValue])
            .range(["#ffffff", "#0038c5"]);

        d3.selectAll("[id*='Zone']")
            .data(data.zoneData)
            .style("fill", function(d){
                    return color(d.value);
                })
            .append("title")
                .text(function(d) {
                      return d.name + "\n" + d.value;
                });
        });
```

I've looked at the docs on [selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) and [thinking with joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) but was not able to figure out how to match the existing elements in my selection with JSON data array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need the polygons to be selected in a specific order, which isn't guaranteed by `.selectAll()`. You also can't reorder them easily, as D3's `.sort()` method works on data, which hasn't been bound to the elements at that point.

One way of fixing this would be "attach" some data manually to the elements that allows to match up elements and data. Then all you need is a key function:

```
d3.selectAll("[id*='Zone']")
        .each(function() { this.__data__ = { zoneID: this.id })
        .data(data.zoneData, function(d) { return d.zoneID; })
        ...
```

The second line here mimics what D3 does internally and creates the attribute that D3 looks for when trying to find bound data.

Comment: Awesome Lars, you did it again! Thanks!